# Laravel4 query cloning

Tags: php, laravel-4, clone

This problem is driving me nuts.
It appears that cloning a query doesn't work as expected since my last composer update.
The weird thing is that if I don't perform `->get()`on the first query clone, the second query executes fine. From the moment I perform the `->get`on both query clones, I receive an error: 
`General error: 2031` 
The `clone` should create a deep copy of the original query, but something doesn't seem right.
Any ideas? Here is my query (it looks more complex than it is, and the query itself is fine):

```
    //Query dates 
    $query_onetime = clone $query; 
    $query_onetime = $query_onetime->join('events_dates', function($join) use ($input_date_start, $input_date_end){ 
                $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_dates.event_id'); 
                    $join->where('events_dates.start_date', "<=", $input_date_end); 
                    $join->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', $input_date_start); 
            }); 

    //Select fields 
    $events_onetime = $query_onetime->select('events.id AS id', 'events.name AS name', 'event_categories.id as category_id', 'event_categories.category as category', 
                    'event_subcategories.id as subcategory_id', 'event_subcategories.subcategory as subcategory', 
                    'short_description', 'time_description', 
                    'price_description', 'nr_going', 'nr_checkedin', 'homepage', 'fbpage', 'profile_pic', 
                    'places.id AS place_id', 'places.name AS place_name', 'lat', 'lng', 'address')
            ->groupBy('events.id')
            ->get(); 

    if(isset($data["include_recurrent"]) && $data["include_recurrent"]){ 

        //Query recurrent dates 
        $query_recurrent = clone $query; 
        $query_recurrent = $query_recurrent->join('events_dates_recurrent', 'events.id', '=', 'events_dates_recurrent.event_id')
            ->where(function($join) use ($input_date_start, $input_date_end) { 
                //Create a dynamic query to get all recurrent dates within the input time interval 
                $query_string = "ABS(DATEDIFF('" . $input_date_start . "', CAST(events_dates_recurrent.start_date AS DATE)) % events_dates_recurrent.repeat_interval) = 0"; 
                $temp_date_start = $input_date_start; 

                while(strtotime($temp_date_start) < strtotime($input_date_end)){ 
                    $temp_date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($temp_date_start . " +1 day")); 
                    //Create a raw query string 
                    $query_string = $query_string . " OR ABS(DATEDIFF('" . $temp_date_start . "', CAST(events_dates_recurrent.start_date AS DATE)) % events_dates_recurrent.repeat_interval) = 0"; 
                } 
                $join->whereRaw($query_string); 
            }); 

        //Select fields 
        $events_recurrent = $query_recurrent->select('events.id AS id', 'events.name AS name', 'event_categories.id as category_id', 'event_categories.category as category', 
                        'event_subcategories.id as subcategory_id', 'event_subcategories.subcategory as subcategory', 
                        'short_description', 'time_description', 
                        'price_description', 'nr_going', 'nr_checkedin', 'homepage', 'fbpage', 'profile_pic', 
                        'places.id AS place_id', 'places.name AS place_name', 'lat', 'lng', 'address')
                ->groupBy('events.id')
                ->get(); 

        $events = array_merge($events_onetime, $events_recurrent);
```

EDIT: for info on request, here is the full query.
I avoided it because it is pretty long.

```
    // Queries events based on map bounds, category and date 
    $query = DB::table('events')
            ->join('places', function($join) use ($data){ 
                $join->on('events.place_id', '=', 'places.id')
                        ->where('places.lat', '>', $data['sw_lat'])
                        ->where('places.lat', '<', $data['ne_lat'])
                        ->where('places.lng', '>', $data['sw_lng'])
                        ->where('places.lng', '<', $data['ne_lng']); 
            })->join('event_categories', function($join) use ($data){ 
                $join->on('events.category_id', '=', 'event_categories.id'); 
            }); 

    // The category id is optional 
    if(isset($data["category_id"])){ 
        $query = $query->where('event_categories.id', '=', $data['category_id']);  
    } 
    //Query subcategory 
    $query = $query->leftJoin('event_subcategories', function($join) use ($data){ 
                $join->on('events.subcategory_id', "=", "event_subcategories.id"); 
            }); 

    //Query keywords 
    $query = $query->join('events_keywords', 'events.id', '=', 'events_keywords.event_id'); 

    //Reverse date format 
    $input_date_start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data["date_start"])); 
    $input_date_end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data["date_end"])); 

    //Query dates 
    $query_onetime = clone $query; 
    $query_onetime = $query_onetime->join('events_dates', function($join) use ($input_date_start, $input_date_end){ 
                $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_dates.event_id'); 
                    $join->where('events_dates.start_date', "<=", $input_date_end); 
                    $join->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', $input_date_start); 
            }); 
    //Select fields 
    $events_onetime = $query_onetime->select('events.id AS id', 'events.name AS name', 'event_categories.id as category_id', 'event_categories.category as category', 
                    'event_subcategories.id as subcategory_id', 'event_subcategories.subcategory as subcategory', 
                    'short_description', 'time_description', 
                    'price_description', 'nr_going', 'nr_checkedin', 'homepage', 'fbpage', 'profile_pic', 
                    'places.id AS place_id', 'places.name AS place_name', 'lat', 'lng', 'address')
            ->groupBy('events.id')
            ->get(); 

    foreach($events_onetime as $event){ 
        $temp_event = EventModel::find($event->id); 
        $event->keywords = $temp_event->keywords; 
    } 

    if(isset($data["include_recurrent"]) && $data["include_recurrent"]){ 

        //Query recurrent dates 
        $query_recurrent = clone $query; 
        $query_recurrent = $query_recurrent->join('events_dates_recurrent', 'events.id', '=', 'events_dates_recurrent.event_id')
            ->where(function($join) use ($input_date_start, $input_date_end) { 
                //Create a dynamic query to get all recurrent dates within the input time interval 
                $query_string = "ABS(DATEDIFF('" . $input_date_start . "', CAST(events_dates_recurrent.start_date AS DATE)) % events_dates_recurrent.repeat_interval) = 0"; 
                $temp_date_start = $input_date_start; 

                while(strtotime($temp_date_start) < strtotime($input_date_end)){ 
                    $temp_date_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($temp_date_start . " +1 day")); 
                    //Create a raw query string 
                    $query_string = $query_string . " OR ABS(DATEDIFF('" . $temp_date_start . "', CAST(events_dates_recurrent.start_date AS DATE)) % events_dates_recurrent.repeat_interval) = 0"; 
                } 
                $join->whereRaw($query_string); 
            }); 

        //Select fields 
        $events_recurrent = $query_recurrent->select('events.id AS id', 'events.name AS name', 'event_categories.id as category_id', 'event_categories.category as category', 
                        'event_subcategories.id as subcategory_id', 'event_subcategories.subcategory as subcategory', 
                        'short_description', 'time_description', 
                        'price_description', 'nr_going', 'nr_checkedin', 'homepage', 'fbpage', 'profile_pic', 
                        'places.id AS place_id', 'places.name AS place_name', 'lat', 'lng', 'address')
                ->groupBy('events.id')
                ->get(); 

        //At this point we just have the events, but we also need the keywords per event. 
        foreach($events_recurrent as $event){ 
            $temp_event = EventModel::find($event->id); 
            $event->keywords = $temp_event->keywords; 
        } 
        $events = array_merge($events_onetime, $events_recurrent); 
    } else { 
        //Else return only the non-recurrent events 
        $events = $events_onetime; 
    }

    return $events; 
}
```

Comment: How about you clone `$query` twice at the beginning? `$query_onetime = clone $query; $query_recurrent = clone $query;`

Comment: No luck... end up with the same result. The weird thing is that if I don't make the get in one of both, then it works for either. But I have to combine the result of the two queries.

Comment: Can you show what `$query` is? MySQL error 2031 seems to be related to binding parameters, btw.

Comment: On your request, I've added the full query. Yes, I've read about that, but I can't seem to figure out where it goes wrong. Also, when I copy the entire query string two times instead of making the clone, surprisingly (or not) it works... obviously I will avoid that, as the query is already very long.

Comment: This could be nothing, but I don't think you have to do `$query = $query->join(etc)`. Just `$query->join(etc)` updates the original `$query` object. You might try cleaning that up to see if that makes a diff.

Comment: You're right, I cleaned that up in my code... thanks for notification, unfortunately I get the same result indeed.

Comment: you might want to re-factor into "query scopes", more maintainable and readable.

Comment: @BrianDillingham Thanks for advice. I'm not very experienced in back end programming yet, so I will certainly look into that.

Comment: @KimGysen luckily for you Laravel makes it super easy :) http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes you just organize your blocks of related query logic into a method on the model and chain them together when you're implementing them, `$model->queryScope()->queryScope();`

Comment: @BrianDillingham Wow, that's neat... should have checked that earlier!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$query` object is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and it maintains a reference to a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` which holds the actual query. According to the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php), the `clone` keyword performs a shallow copy of an object, meaning that references are copied as references. Thus, `$query` and `$query_onetime` both maintain a reference to the same `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instance and changes to one affect the other.

This issue with needing to clone the underlying query has been fixed in Laravel 4.1, but if you don't want to upgrade you can try this workaround:

```
$query_onetime = clone $query;
$query_onetime->setQuery(clone $query->getQuery());
// Any additional joins specific to $query_onetime
```

Comment: Thanks, so that's what it is. I get an error, mentioning `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getQuery()`. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @BrokenBinary Take a close look at the question. The OP isn't using Eloquent.

Comment: When returning `get_class($query)`, I receive `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`. The version is 4.2.16.

Comment: This issue should have been fixed in 4.1, and as @lukasgeiter mentioned, you aren't using Eloquent like I assumed. The issue I answered for isn't the issue you're having.

Comment: Yeah... except I'm already using 4.2.16 according to my artisan tool :-/

Comment: Right... I'm running 4.2.11 and I can clone a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object just fine. I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Don't worry, upvoted, thanks for your help anyway. I'm going to split up the query string into scopes as suggested by @BrianDillingham, and I'll just build it two times. It's not a problem.